# express router not calling get request returning with empty obj

Tags: node.js, express, get, routes

I am calling get request from angular 4 . I have used expressjs router . my get call not coming to my router function . It works fine if I use a dummy id . 
Here is my code for front end

```
getOnlineUser(){
console.log('nline --')
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.http.get(this.url+'/chat/getonlineusers')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(res => {
      resolve(res);
    }, (err) => {
      reject(err);
    });
}); }
```

here is my expressjs router code

```
router.get('/getonlineusers', function(req, res, next) {
 console.log('here it is---+=============---------- ')
 // the above console not working
 OnlineUsers.find({}, function (err, Users) {
  console.log(Users)
if (err) return next(err);
res.json(Users);
});
});
```

this router works fine if I use dummy id like this `/getonlineusers/:id`

server file is

```
app.use('/chat', chat);
```

what could be the error

Comment: When you look in the Network section of your browser's dev tools, what is the URL of the request that is being performed?

Comment: the same i used here `/getonlineusers` and it show empty obj in response

Comment: Could you post the full URL here so we can check it for you? Do you have any other routes configured on your server that might be matching this request, possibly something left over from an earlier experiment or a copy/paste you forgot to update?

Comment: Try changing it to `/getonlineusers/:id` (as you mentioned in the question) and then add logging to check what value `id` has: `console.log(req.params.id)`. Might shed some light on what's going on.

Comment: this consoling the id exactly I send @skirtle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was calling **/getonlineusers** from front end and there was a route named **/:room** before **/getonlineusers** and my ajax call was going to **/:room** instead of **/getonlineusers**

so i put the route  **/getonlineusers** above from **/:room**  and thats **worked**

Answer (score 0):

About the client side you do not need, to wrap your request in a promise,
 a better way is just to use the `toPromise()` from `rxjs`.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

getOnlineUser() {
   return this.http.get(`{this.url}/chat/getonlineusers`)
     .map(res => res.json())
     .toPromise();
 }

// back seems ok
router.get('/getonlineusers', function (req, res, next) {
  OnlineUsers.find({}, function (err, users) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    res.json(users);
  });
});
```

Comment: this is not the problem

Comment: agree, it is more like a suggestion not answer

Comment: my get call not coming to express router